# You have an error in your SQL syntax; and $db->query(ERROR: 1)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I tried to so hard to find a solution for this but in vain.
I could insert into the db successfully all the data, but still I get the same problem.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

I did escape my variables, added ticks ` to the table, but still the same problem.

```
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO `uploadusers` (uploadusers.uname, uploadusers.phone, uploadusers.mail, uploadusers.lng, uploadusers.path) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userName) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userPhone)."', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userMail)."', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userLng)."', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $path)."')");
                if ($db->query($insert)) {
                        echo "New record created successfully";
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $insert . "<br>" . $db->error;
                    }
```

When I echo `$insert` gives me '1' and `$db->error` gives me that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're calling `query()` twice.

So remove one of them and just do `if ($insert)) {`

```
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO... ");
    if ($insert) {
```

Comment: I was about to do so, but they asked me to wait 9 min >.> so guess I gave it a lot of time :p

Comment: @Bououm *hehe*, no problemo ;-)